# In R's ROCR package, is it an error for cutoffs to be infinity?

Tags: r, prediction, roc, model-evaluation, rocr

In `R`, there is an ROC package called `ROCR`. In their default simple example, they have:

```
library(ROCR)
data(ROCR.simple)
pred <- prediction( ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels)
pred@cutoffs

[[1]]
  [1]         Inf 0.991096434 0.984667270 0.984599159 0.983494405 0.970641299
  [7] 0.959417835 0.945548941 0.943432189 0.938583020 0.932159806 0.930846938
 [13] 0.912325837 0.911723615
```

The first cutoff appears to be infinity instead of 1. Is this a typo or can it be interpreted correctly?

Comment: I believe this is a statistical question asked as an R question.